# Why mysql query is slow without quotation mark?

Tags: mysql

The table DDL as flows:

```
CREATE TABLE `video` (
  `short_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `prob` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `star_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `qipu_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cloud_url` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_identical` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quality` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`short_id`),
  KEY `ix_video_short_id` (`short_id`),
  KEY `sid` (`star_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The video table has 4.5 million lines. 
I execute the same query in mysql shell client as flows. except in where clause the star_id equal to a value with quatation mark, another not as flows.

```
select * from video where star_id="215343405";
12914 rows in set (0.22 sec)

select * from video where star_id=215343405;
12914 rows in set (3.17 sec)
```

the one with quatation mark is 10x faster then another(I have create index on star_id).i watch out the slow one does not use the index. I just wonder how mysql process the query?

```
mysql> explain select * from video where star_id=215343405;
```

Thanks advance!

Comment: Why isn't star_id an integer?

Comment: Excellent data type choice for `star_id`! *</sarcasm>*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered in the [**manual**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html):

> For comparisons of a string column with a number, MySQL cannot use an
> index on the column to look up the value quickly. If str_col is an
> indexed string column, the index cannot be used when performing the
> lookup in the following statement:
>
> `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE str_col=1;`
>
> The reason for this is that there are many different strings that may convert to the value 1, such as '1', ' 1', or '1a'.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use Quotation marks mysql uses the value as an int and must convert the value for every record. Therefor the db needs a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes define the expression as a string, whereas without the single quote it is evaluated as a number. This means that MySQL is forced to perform a [Type Conversion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html) to convert the number to a `CHAR` to do a proper comparison.

As the doc above says,

> For comparisons of a string column with a number, MySQL cannot use an
>   index on the column to look up the value quickly. If str_col is an
>   indexed string column, the index cannot be used when performing the
>   lookup...

However, the inverse of that is not true and while the index can be used, using a string as a value causes a poor execution plan (as illustrated by jkavalik's [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb300/1)) where `using where` is used instead of the faster `using index condition`. The main difference between the two is that the former requires a row lookup and the latter can get the data directly from the index.

You should definitely modify the column data type (assuming it truly is only meant to contain numbers) to the appropriate data type ASAP, but make sure that no queries are actually using single quotes, otherwise you'll be back where you started.